# ProtocolBufferDecodeError, "truncated" when inserting key using ndb.Key(urlsafe=

Tags: google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python

I am receiving an error using the ndb.Key() method using urlsafe parameter.
You will see lots of logging statements I've been using to temporarily find the source of my error.  I've narrowed it down to this line:

```
resource_section = ndb.Key(urlsafe=request.resource_section_key
```

I used the same syntax to insert the resource key in the line immediately before this one, and it was successful.  I have verified that the entity exists in the datastore.  I've been working with this for a couple of days, and I hope one of you can see something I'm missing.

Here is the code:

```
    if request.knowledge_key:
        logging.info("Logging: class KnowledgeMessageApi.insert_knowledge() - request.knowledge_key = " + request.knowledge_key) 
        # If no key exists, then we can assume it needs to be inserted
        # into the datastore.  Overwrite any exiting values with what
        # is passed into the method
        kno=ndb.Key(urlsafe=request.knowledge_key).get()
        kno.knowledge = request.knowledge
        kno.resource = ndb.Key(urlsafe=request.resource_key)
        kno.resource_section = ndb.Key(urlsafe=request.resource_section_key)
        kno.types = request.types
        kno.page = request.page
        kno.keywords = request.keywords
        kno.put()

    else:
        logging.info("Logging: class KnowledgeMessageApi.insert_knowledge() - request.knowledge = " + request.knowledge) 
        logging.info("Logging: class KnowledgeMessageApi.insert_knowledge() - request.resource_key = " + request.resource_key) 
        logging.info("Logging: class KnowledgeMessageApi.insert_knowledge() - request.resource_section_key = " + request.resource_section_key)
        types_string = ""
        for item in request.types:
            types_string += item.strip()
        logging.info("Logging: class KnowledgeMessageApi.insert_knowledge() - request.types = " + types_string)

        logging.info("Logging: class KnowledgeMessageApi.insert_knowledge() - request.page = " + str(request.page)) 
        keywords_string = ""
        for item in request.keywords:
            keywords_string += item.strip()
        logging.info("Logging: class KnowledgeMessageApi.insert_knowledge() - request.keywords = " + keywords_string) 
        #get resource key and name
        Knowledge(parent=PARENT_KEY,
                  knowledge=request.knowledge, 
                  resource = ndb.Key(urlsafe=request.resource_key),
                  resource_section = ndb.Key(urlsafe=request.resource_section_key),
                  types = types_string.split(","),
                  page = request.page,
                  keywords = keywords_string.split(",")
                  ).put()

    return request
```

My stack trace follows:

```
    INFO     2016-07-18 18:37:16,440 module.py:788] default: "POST /_ah/spi/BackendService.getApiConfigs HTTP/1.1" 200 3958
INFO     2016-07-18 18:37:16,649 apiuser.py:20] Logging: Class ApiUser.__init__ - beginning.
INFO     2016-07-18 18:37:16,649 apiuser.py:22] Logging: Class ApiUser.__init__ - endpoints_user = endpoints.get_current_user()
INFO     2016-07-18 18:37:16,649 apiuser.py:24] Logging: Class ApiUser.__init__ - an endpoints_user exists.
INFO     2016-07-18 18:37:16,649 apiuser.py:44] Logging: Class ApiUser.__init__ - locating from endpoints email.
INFO     2016-07-18 18:37:16,661 apiuser.py:53] Logging: Class ApiUser.__init__ - attempting to populate the object.
INFO     2016-07-18 18:37:16,661 apiuser.py:57] Logging: Class ApiUser.__init__ - self.email = knouser_object.contact_email.
INFO     2016-07-18 18:37:16,661 apiuser.py:59] Logging: Class ApiUser.__init__ - self.email = knouser_object.contact_email.
INFO     2016-07-18 18:37:16,661 apiuser.py:61] Logging: Class ApiUser.__init__ - self.user_id = knouser_object.login_user_id.
INFO     2016-07-18 18:37:16,661 apiuser.py:63] Logging: Class ApiUser.__init__ - self.knouser_key_urlsafe = knouser_object.key.urlsafe().
INFO     2016-07-18 18:37:16,661 apiuser.py:65] Logging: Class ApiUser.__init__ - if knouser_object.organization:.
INFO     2016-07-18 18:37:16,661 apiuser.py:67] Logging: Class ApiUser.__init__ - self.org_key_urlsafe = knouser_object.organization.urlsafe().
INFO     2016-07-18 18:37:16,661 api_knowledge.py:56] Logging: class KnowledgeMessageApi.insert_knowledge() - authenticated_user.email = stewart.jamie@swchristian.com
INFO     2016-07-18 18:37:16,662 api_knowledge.py:58] Logging: class KnowledgeMessageApi.insert_knowledge() - authenticated_user.get_org_key()
INFO     2016-07-18 18:37:16,662 api_knowledge.py:75] Logging: class KnowledgeMessageApi.insert_knowledge() - request.knowledge = This is a test insert of knowledge.
INFO     2016-07-18 18:37:16,662 api_knowledge.py:76] Logging: class KnowledgeMessageApi.insert_knowledge() - request.resource_key = ahdkZXZ-amFtZXNzdGUtc2Nob29sLWFwcHJLCxIGRW50aXR5IhFvcmdhbml6YXRpb25fcm9vdAwLEgxPcmdhbml6YXRpb24YgICAgIDQpwoMCxIIUmVzb3VyY2UYgICAgIDElQoM
INFO     2016-07-18 18:37:16,662 api_knowledge.py:77] Logging: class KnowledgeMessageApi.insert_knowledge() - request.resource_section_key = ahdkZXZ-amFtZXNzdGUtc2Nob29sLWFwcHJSCxIGRW50aXR5IhFvcmdhbml6YXRpb25fcm9vdAwLEgxPcmdhbml6YXRpb24YgICAgIDQpwoMCxIPUmVzb3VyY2VTZWN0aW9uGICAgICA5OU
INFO     2016-07-18 18:37:16,662 api_knowledge.py:81] Logging: class KnowledgeMessageApi.insert_knowledge() - request.types = literature
INFO     2016-07-18 18:37:16,662 api_knowledge.py:83] Logging: class KnowledgeMessageApi.insert_knowledge() - request.page = 2
INFO     2016-07-18 18:37:16,662 api_knowledge.py:87] Logging: class KnowledgeMessageApi.insert_knowledge() - request.keywords = 
ERROR    2016-07-18 18:37:16,662 service.py:191] Encountered unexpected error from ProtoRPC method implementation: ProtocolBufferDecodeError (truncated)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/protorpc-1.0/protorpc/wsgi/service.py", line 181, in protorpc_service_app
    response = method(instance, request)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/endpoints-1.0/endpoints/api_config.py", line 1331, in invoke_remote
    return remote_method(service_instance, request)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/protorpc-1.0/protorpc/remote.py", line 414, in invoke_remote_method
    response = method(service_instance, request)
  File "/Users/jamesste/Documents/code/jamesste-school-app/api_knowledge.py", line 92, in insert_knowledge
    resource_section = ndb.Key(urlsafe=request.resource_section_key),
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/ndb/key.py", line 230, in __new__
    self.__namespace) = self._parse_from_ref(cls, **kwargs)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/ndb/key.py", line 318, in _parse_from_ref
    reference = _ReferenceFromSerialized(serialized)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/ndb/key.py", line 821, in _ReferenceFromSerialized
    return entity_pb.Reference(serialized)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/datastore/entity_pb.py", line 1782, in __init__
    if contents is not None: self.MergeFromString(contents)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/net/proto/ProtocolBuffer.py", line 152, in MergeFromString
    self.MergePartialFromString(s)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/net/proto/ProtocolBuffer.py", line 168, in MergePartialFromString
    self.TryMerge(d)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/datastore/entity_pb.py", line 1927, in TryMerge
    d.skip(length)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/net/proto/ProtocolBuffer.py", line 650, in skip
    if self.idx + n > self.limit: raise ProtocolBufferDecodeError, "truncated"
ProtocolBufferDecodeError: truncated
INFO     2016-07-18 18:37:16,671 module.py:788] default: "POST /_ah/spi/KnowledgeMessageApi.insert_knowledge HTTP/1.1" 500 512
INFO     2016-07-18 18:37:16,672 module.py:788] default: "POST /_ah/api/knowledge/v1/knowledge?alt=json HTTP/1.1" 503 196
```

The model:

```
class Knowledge(ndb.Model):
    resource=ndb.KeyProperty(kind=Resource)
    resource_section=ndb.KeyProperty(kind=ResourceSection)
    types=ndb.StringProperty(repeated=True) #system-level categories
    knowledge=ndb.StringProperty()
    page=ndb.IntegerProperty()
    keywords=ndb.StringProperty(repeated=True) #unregulated grouping types
```

Proof that the resource_section entity exists:
[resource_section entity screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F4zen.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much head-scratching and snack breaks I did what I never do... I intervened manually to get positive results and as a result lost the state that generated the error.  So, I am posting this as an answer, however it is not a definitive one.  So, I commented out that line of code and completed the insert sans the ResourceSection key.  Since the application breaks when there is a None value in that property, I manually inserted the key via the datastore utility on Google Cloud Platform.  From this point forward the code executed normally, both edit and insert.  While I don't know why I received the error, it could have something to do with this being the first Knowledge entity insert.  At any rate, I do not have the issue anymore.

Comment: so I have sub-entities stored in the localPacked format;  after I edit the record thru the web UI, I also get this error.  It's my guess that the data stored is being truncated or otherwise corrupted on resave via the web UI